# mysqldump and send it to another server without save on local machine

Tags: mysql, linux, database, server

i have a database server ( MySQL ) that does not have enough free space to save dump of MySQL. i want to create dump on it and send to archive server straight without save on local host because lack of space. how can i do this on my local database server ?
all of my servers are Linux base.
thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
mysqldump -u MYSQL_USER -p'MYSQL_PASSWORD' YOUR_DATABASE | gzip -c | ssh you@your_host 'cat > ~/backup.sql.gz'
```